# Wind rose WRF-PYTHON

Tags: wind, wrf, python, simulation

I'm trying to plot a windrose but I don't know how to get the variables ws and wd. Is there any variable in the wrf output that can be used to make a windrose?

I tried with 'wspd' et 'wdir' but I coudn't make my figure.

This is my code:

```
 # Open the NetCDF file
ncfile = Dataset("wrfout_d03_2017-06-17_15:00:00")


# Extract the pressure, geopotential height, and wind variables


p = getvar(ncfile, "pressure")
z = getvar(ncfile, "z", units="m")
u = getvar(ncfile, "ua", units="m s-1")
v = getvar(ncfile, "va", units="m s-1")
#wspd = getvar(ncfile, "wspd_wdir", units="m s-1")[0,:]



ws = getvar(ncfile, "wspd")[:]
wd = getvar(ncfile, "wdir")[:]


fig=plt.figure()

ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(ws, wd, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
ax.set_legend()


plt.show()
```

## This is the header of the netCDF file:

```
netcdf wrfout_d03_2017-06-17_19\:05\:00 {
dimensions:
    Time = UNLIMITED ; // (1 currently)
    DateStrLen = 19 ;
    west_east = 486 ;
    south_north = 429 ;
    bottom_top = 47 ;
    bottom_top_stag = 48 ;
    soil_layers_stag = 4 ;
    west_east_stag = 487 ;
    south_north_stag = 430 ;
variables:
    char Times(Time, DateStrLen) ;
    float XLAT(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        XLAT:FieldType = 104 ;
        XLAT:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        XLAT:description = "LATITUDE, SOUTH IS NEGATIVE" ;
        XLAT:units = "degree_north" ;
        XLAT:stagger = "" ;
        XLAT:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT" ;
    float XLONG(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        XLONG:FieldType = 104 ;
        XLONG:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        XLONG:description = "LONGITUDE, WEST IS NEGATIVE" ;
        XLONG:units = "degree_east" ;
        XLONG:stagger = "" ;
        XLONG:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT" ;
    float LU_INDEX(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        LU_INDEX:FieldType = 104 ;
        LU_INDEX:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        LU_INDEX:description = "LAND USE CATEGORY" ;
        LU_INDEX:units = "" ;
        LU_INDEX:stagger = "" ;
        LU_INDEX:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float ZNU(Time, bottom_top) ;
        ZNU:FieldType = 104 ;
        ZNU:MemoryOrder = "Z  " ;
        ZNU:description = "eta values on half (mass) levels" ;
        ZNU:units = "" ;
        ZNU:stagger = "" ;
    float ZNW(Time, bottom_top_stag) ;
        ZNW:FieldType = 104 ;
        ZNW:MemoryOrder = "Z  " ;
        ZNW:description = "eta values on full (w) levels" ;
        ZNW:units = "" ;
        ZNW:stagger = "Z" ;
    float ZS(Time, soil_layers_stag) ;
        ZS:FieldType = 104 ;
        ZS:MemoryOrder = "Z  " ;
        ZS:description = "DEPTHS OF CENTERS OF SOIL LAYERS" ;
        ZS:units = "m" ;
        ZS:stagger = "Z" ;
    float DZS(Time, soil_layers_stag) ;
        DZS:FieldType = 104 ;
        DZS:MemoryOrder = "Z  " ;
        DZS:description = "THICKNESSES OF SOIL LAYERS" ;
        DZS:units = "m" ;
        DZS:stagger = "Z" ;
    float VAR_SSO(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        VAR_SSO:FieldType = 104 ;
        VAR_SSO:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        VAR_SSO:description = "variance of subgrid-scale orography" ;
        VAR_SSO:units = "m2" ;
        VAR_SSO:stagger = "" ;
        VAR_SSO:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float U(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east_stag) ;
        U:FieldType = 104 ;
        U:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        U:description = "x-wind component" ;
        U:units = "m s-1" ;
        U:stagger = "X" ;
        U:coordinates = "XLONG_U XLAT_U XTIME" ;
    float V(Time, bottom_top, south_north_stag, west_east) ;
        V:FieldType = 104 ;
        V:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        V:description = "y-wind component" ;
        V:units = "m s-1" ;
        V:stagger = "Y" ;
        V:coordinates = "XLONG_V XLAT_V XTIME" ;
    float W(Time, bottom_top_stag, south_north, west_east) ;
        W:FieldType = 104 ;
        W:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        W:description = "z-wind component" ;
        W:units = "m s-1" ;
        W:stagger = "Z" ;
        W:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float PH(Time, bottom_top_stag, south_north, west_east) ;
        PH:FieldType = 104 ;
        PH:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        PH:description = "perturbation geopotential" ;
        PH:units = "m2 s-2" ;
        PH:stagger = "Z" ;
        PH:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float PHB(Time, bottom_top_stag, south_north, west_east) ;
        PHB:FieldType = 104 ;
        PHB:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        PHB:description = "base-state geopotential" ;
        PHB:units = "m2 s-2" ;
        PHB:stagger = "Z" ;
        PHB:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float T(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;
        T:FieldType = 104 ;
        T:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        T:description = "perturbation potential temperature (theta-t0)" ;
        T:units = "K" ;
        T:stagger = "" ;
        T:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float HFX_FORCE(Time) ;
        HFX_FORCE:FieldType = 104 ;
        HFX_FORCE:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        HFX_FORCE:description = "SCM ideal surface sensible heat flux" ;
        HFX_FORCE:units = "W m-2" ;
        HFX_FORCE:stagger = "" ;
    float LH_FORCE(Time) ;
        LH_FORCE:FieldType = 104 ;
        LH_FORCE:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        LH_FORCE:description = "SCM ideal surface latent heat flux" ;
        LH_FORCE:units = "W m-2" ;
        LH_FORCE:stagger = "" ;
    float TSK_FORCE(Time) ;
        TSK_FORCE:FieldType = 104 ;
        TSK_FORCE:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        TSK_FORCE:description = "SCM ideal surface skin temperature" ;
        TSK_FORCE:units = "W m-2" ;
        TSK_FORCE:stagger = "" ;
    float HFX_FORCE_TEND(Time) ;
        HFX_FORCE_TEND:FieldType = 104 ;
        HFX_FORCE_TEND:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        HFX_FORCE_TEND:description = "SCM ideal surface sensible heat flux tendency" ;
        HFX_FORCE_TEND:units = "W m-2 s-1" ;
        HFX_FORCE_TEND:stagger = "" ;
    float LH_FORCE_TEND(Time) ;
        LH_FORCE_TEND:FieldType = 104 ;
        LH_FORCE_TEND:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        LH_FORCE_TEND:description = "SCM ideal surface latent heat flux tendency" ;
        LH_FORCE_TEND:units = "W m-2 s-1" ;
        LH_FORCE_TEND:stagger = "" ;
    float TSK_FORCE_TEND(Time) ;
        TSK_FORCE_TEND:FieldType = 104 ;
        TSK_FORCE_TEND:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        TSK_FORCE_TEND:description = "SCM ideal surface skin temperature tendency" ;
        TSK_FORCE_TEND:units = "W m-2 s-1" ;
        TSK_FORCE_TEND:stagger = "" ;
    float MU(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        MU:FieldType = 104 ;
        MU:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        MU:description = "perturbation dry air mass in column" ;
        MU:units = "Pa" ;
        MU:stagger = "" ;
        MU:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float MUB(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        MUB:FieldType = 104 ;
        MUB:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        MUB:description = "base state dry air mass in column" ;
        MUB:units = "Pa" ;
        MUB:stagger = "" ;
        MUB:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float NEST_POS(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        NEST_POS:FieldType = 104 ;
        NEST_POS:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        NEST_POS:description = "-" ;
        NEST_POS:units = "-" ;
        NEST_POS:stagger = "" ;
        NEST_POS:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float P(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;
        P:FieldType = 104 ;
        P:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        P:description = "perturbation pressure" ;
        P:units = "Pa" ;
        P:stagger = "" ;
        P:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float PB(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;
        PB:FieldType = 104 ;
        PB:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        PB:description = "BASE STATE PRESSURE" ;
        PB:units = "Pa" ;
        PB:stagger = "" ;
        PB:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float FNM(Time, bottom_top) ;
        FNM:FieldType = 104 ;
        FNM:MemoryOrder = "Z  " ;
        FNM:description = "upper weight for vertical stretching" ;
        FNM:units = "" ;
        FNM:stagger = "" ;
    float FNP(Time, bottom_top) ;
        FNP:FieldType = 104 ;
        FNP:MemoryOrder = "Z  " ;
        FNP:description = "lower weight for vertical stretching" ;
        FNP:units = "" ;
        FNP:stagger = "" ;
    float RDNW(Time, bottom_top) ;
        RDNW:FieldType = 104 ;
        RDNW:MemoryOrder = "Z  " ;
        RDNW:description = "inverse d(eta) values between full (w) levels" ;
        RDNW:units = "" ;
        RDNW:stagger = "" ;
    float RDN(Time, bottom_top) ;
        RDN:FieldType = 104 ;
        RDN:MemoryOrder = "Z  " ;
        RDN:description = "inverse d(eta) values between half (mass) levels" ;
        RDN:units = "" ;
        RDN:stagger = "" ;
    float DNW(Time, bottom_top) ;
        DNW:FieldType = 104 ;
        DNW:MemoryOrder = "Z  " ;
        DNW:description = "d(eta) values between full (w) levels" ;
        DNW:units = "" ;
        DNW:stagger = "" ;
    float DN(Time, bottom_top) ;
        DN:FieldType = 104 ;
        DN:MemoryOrder = "Z  " ;
        DN:description = "d(eta) values between half (mass) levels" ;
        DN:units = "" ;
        DN:stagger = "" ;
    float CFN(Time) ;
        CFN:FieldType = 104 ;
        CFN:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        CFN:description = "extrapolation constant" ;
        CFN:units = "" ;
        CFN:stagger = "" ;
    float CFN1(Time) ;
        CFN1:FieldType = 104 ;
        CFN1:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        CFN1:description = "extrapolation constant" ;
        CFN1:units = "" ;
        CFN1:stagger = "" ;
    int THIS_IS_AN_IDEAL_RUN(Time) ;
        THIS_IS_AN_IDEAL_RUN:FieldType = 106 ;
        THIS_IS_AN_IDEAL_RUN:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        THIS_IS_AN_IDEAL_RUN:description = "T/F flag: this is an ARW ideal simulation" ;
        THIS_IS_AN_IDEAL_RUN:units = "-" ;
        THIS_IS_AN_IDEAL_RUN:stagger = "" ;
    float P_HYD(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;
        P_HYD:FieldType = 104 ;
        P_HYD:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        P_HYD:description = "hydrostatic pressure" ;
        P_HYD:units = "Pa" ;
        P_HYD:stagger = "" ;
        P_HYD:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float Q2(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        Q2:FieldType = 104 ;
        Q2:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        Q2:description = "QV at 2 M" ;
        Q2:units = "kg kg-1" ;
        Q2:stagger = "" ;
        Q2:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float T2(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        T2:FieldType = 104 ;
        T2:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        T2:description = "TEMP at 2 M" ;
        T2:units = "K" ;
        T2:stagger = "" ;
        T2:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float TH2(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        TH2:FieldType = 104 ;
        TH2:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        TH2:description = "POT TEMP at 2 M" ;
        TH2:units = "K" ;
        TH2:stagger = "" ;
        TH2:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float PSFC(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        PSFC:FieldType = 104 ;
        PSFC:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        PSFC:description = "SFC PRESSURE" ;
        PSFC:units = "Pa" ;
        PSFC:stagger = "" ;
        PSFC:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float U10(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        U10:FieldType = 104 ;
        U10:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        U10:description = "U at 10 M" ;
        U10:units = "m s-1" ;
        U10:stagger = "" ;
        U10:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float V10(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        V10:FieldType = 104 ;
        V10:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        V10:description = "V at 10 M" ;
        V10:units = "m s-1" ;
        V10:stagger = "" ;
        V10:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float RDX(Time) ;
        RDX:FieldType = 104 ;
        RDX:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        RDX:description = "INVERSE X GRID LENGTH" ;
        RDX:units = "" ;
        RDX:stagger = "" ;
    float RDY(Time) ;
        RDY:FieldType = 104 ;
        RDY:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        RDY:description = "INVERSE Y GRID LENGTH" ;
        RDY:units = "" ;
        RDY:stagger = "" ;
    float RESM(Time) ;
        RESM:FieldType = 104 ;
        RESM:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        RESM:description = "TIME WEIGHT CONSTANT FOR SMALL STEPS" ;
        RESM:units = "" ;
        RESM:stagger = "" ;
    float ZETATOP(Time) ;
        ZETATOP:FieldType = 104 ;
        ZETATOP:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        ZETATOP:description = "ZETA AT MODEL TOP" ;
        ZETATOP:units = "" ;
        ZETATOP:stagger = "" ;
    float CF1(Time) ;
        CF1:FieldType = 104 ;
        CF1:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        CF1:description = "2nd order extrapolation constant" ;
        CF1:units = "" ;
        CF1:stagger = "" ;
    float CF2(Time) ;
        CF2:FieldType = 104 ;
        CF2:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        CF2:description = "2nd order extrapolation constant" ;
        CF2:units = "" ;
        CF2:stagger = "" ;
    float CF3(Time) ;
        CF3:FieldType = 104 ;
        CF3:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        CF3:description = "2nd order extrapolation constant" ;
        CF3:units = "" ;
        CF3:stagger = "" ;
    int ITIMESTEP(Time) ;
        ITIMESTEP:FieldType = 106 ;
        ITIMESTEP:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        ITIMESTEP:description = "" ;
        ITIMESTEP:units = "" ;
        ITIMESTEP:stagger = "" ;
    float XTIME(Time) ;
        XTIME:FieldType = 104 ;
        XTIME:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        XTIME:description = "minutes since 2017-06-17 00:00:00" ;
        XTIME:units = "minutes since 2017-06-17 00:00:00" ;
        XTIME:stagger = "" ;
    float QVAPOR(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;
        QVAPOR:FieldType = 104 ;
        QVAPOR:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        QVAPOR:description = "Water vapor mixing ratio" ;
        QVAPOR:units = "kg kg-1" ;
        QVAPOR:stagger = "" ;
        QVAPOR:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float QCLOUD(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;
        QCLOUD:FieldType = 104 ;
        QCLOUD:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        QCLOUD:description = "Cloud water mixing ratio" ;
        QCLOUD:units = "kg kg-1" ;
        QCLOUD:stagger = "" ;
        QCLOUD:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float QRAIN(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;
        QRAIN:FieldType = 104 ;
        QRAIN:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        QRAIN:description = "Rain water mixing ratio" ;
        QRAIN:units = "kg kg-1" ;
        QRAIN:stagger = "" ;
        QRAIN:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float QICE(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;
        QICE:FieldType = 104 ;
        QICE:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        QICE:description = "Ice mixing ratio" ;
        QICE:units = "kg kg-1" ;
        QICE:stagger = "" ;
        QICE:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float QSNOW(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;
        QSNOW:FieldType = 104 ;
        QSNOW:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        QSNOW:description = "Snow mixing ratio" ;
        QSNOW:units = "kg kg-1" ;
        QSNOW:stagger = "" ;
        QSNOW:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float QGRAUP(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;
        QGRAUP:FieldType = 104 ;
        QGRAUP:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        QGRAUP:description = "Graupel mixing ratio" ;
        QGRAUP:units = "kg kg-1" ;
        QGRAUP:stagger = "" ;
        QGRAUP:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float QNICE(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;
        QNICE:FieldType = 104 ;
        QNICE:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        QNICE:description = "Ice Number concentration" ;
        QNICE:units = "  kg-1" ;
        QNICE:stagger = "" ;
        QNICE:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float QNRAIN(Time, bottom_top, south_north, west_east) ;
        QNRAIN:FieldType = 104 ;
        QNRAIN:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        QNRAIN:description = "Rain Number concentration" ;
        QNRAIN:units = "  kg(-1)" ;
        QNRAIN:stagger = "" ;
        QNRAIN:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float SHDMAX(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        SHDMAX:FieldType = 104 ;
        SHDMAX:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        SHDMAX:description = "ANNUAL MAX VEG FRACTION" ;
        SHDMAX:units = "" ;
        SHDMAX:stagger = "" ;
        SHDMAX:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float SHDMIN(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        SHDMIN:FieldType = 104 ;
        SHDMIN:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        SHDMIN:description = "ANNUAL MIN VEG FRACTION" ;
        SHDMIN:units = "" ;
        SHDMIN:stagger = "" ;
        SHDMIN:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float SNOALB(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        SNOALB:FieldType = 104 ;
        SNOALB:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        SNOALB:description = "ANNUAL MAX SNOW ALBEDO IN FRACTION" ;
        SNOALB:units = "" ;
        SNOALB:stagger = "" ;
        SNOALB:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float TSLB(Time, soil_layers_stag, south_north, west_east) ;
        TSLB:FieldType = 104 ;
        TSLB:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        TSLB:description = "SOIL TEMPERATURE" ;
        TSLB:units = "K" ;
        TSLB:stagger = "Z" ;
        TSLB:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float SMOIS(Time, soil_layers_stag, south_north, west_east) ;
        SMOIS:FieldType = 104 ;
        SMOIS:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        SMOIS:description = "SOIL MOISTURE" ;
        SMOIS:units = "m3 m-3" ;
        SMOIS:stagger = "Z" ;
        SMOIS:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float SH2O(Time, soil_layers_stag, south_north, west_east) ;
        SH2O:FieldType = 104 ;
        SH2O:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        SH2O:description = "SOIL LIQUID WATER" ;
        SH2O:units = "m3 m-3" ;
        SH2O:stagger = "Z" ;
        SH2O:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float SMCREL(Time, soil_layers_stag, south_north, west_east) ;
        SMCREL:FieldType = 104 ;
        SMCREL:MemoryOrder = "XYZ" ;
        SMCREL:description = "RELATIVE SOIL MOISTURE" ;
        SMCREL:units = "" ;
        SMCREL:stagger = "Z" ;
        SMCREL:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float SEAICE(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        SEAICE:FieldType = 104 ;
        SEAICE:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        SEAICE:description = "SEA ICE FLAG" ;
        SEAICE:units = "" ;
        SEAICE:stagger = "" ;
        SEAICE:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float XICEM(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        XICEM:FieldType = 104 ;
        XICEM:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        XICEM:description = "SEA ICE FLAG (PREVIOUS STEP)" ;
        XICEM:units = "" ;
        XICEM:stagger = "" ;
        XICEM:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float SFROFF(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        SFROFF:FieldType = 104 ;
        SFROFF:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        SFROFF:description = "SURFACE RUNOFF" ;
        SFROFF:units = "mm" ;
        SFROFF:stagger = "" ;
        SFROFF:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float UDROFF(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        UDROFF:FieldType = 104 ;
        UDROFF:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        UDROFF:description = "UNDERGROUND RUNOFF" ;
        UDROFF:units = "mm" ;
        UDROFF:stagger = "" ;
        UDROFF:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    int IVGTYP(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        IVGTYP:FieldType = 106 ;
        IVGTYP:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        IVGTYP:description = "DOMINANT VEGETATION CATEGORY" ;
        IVGTYP:units = "" ;
        IVGTYP:stagger = "" ;
        IVGTYP:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    int ISLTYP(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        ISLTYP:FieldType = 106 ;
        ISLTYP:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        ISLTYP:description = "DOMINANT SOIL CATEGORY" ;
        ISLTYP:units = "" ;
        ISLTYP:stagger = "" ;
        ISLTYP:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float VEGFRA(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        VEGFRA:FieldType = 104 ;
        VEGFRA:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        VEGFRA:description = "VEGETATION FRACTION" ;
        VEGFRA:units = "" ;
        VEGFRA:stagger = "" ;
        VEGFRA:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float GRDFLX(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        GRDFLX:FieldType = 104 ;
        GRDFLX:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        GRDFLX:description = "GROUND HEAT FLUX" ;
        GRDFLX:units = "W m-2" ;
        GRDFLX:stagger = "" ;
        GRDFLX:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float ACGRDFLX(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        ACGRDFLX:FieldType = 104 ;
        ACGRDFLX:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        ACGRDFLX:description = "ACCUMULATED GROUND HEAT FLUX" ;
        ACGRDFLX:units = "J m-2" ;
        ACGRDFLX:stagger = "" ;
        ACGRDFLX:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float ACSNOM(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        ACSNOM:FieldType = 104 ;
        ACSNOM:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        ACSNOM:description = "ACCUMULATED MELTED SNOW" ;
        ACSNOM:units = "kg m-2" ;
        ACSNOM:stagger = "" ;
        ACSNOM:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float SNOW(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        SNOW:FieldType = 104 ;
        SNOW:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        SNOW:description = "SNOW WATER EQUIVALENT" ;
        SNOW:units = "kg m-2" ;
        SNOW:stagger = "" ;
        SNOW:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float SNOWH(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        SNOWH:FieldType = 104 ;
        SNOWH:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        SNOWH:description = "PHYSICAL SNOW DEPTH" ;
        SNOWH:units = "m" ;
        SNOWH:stagger = "" ;
        SNOWH:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float CANWAT(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        CANWAT:FieldType = 104 ;
        CANWAT:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        CANWAT:description = "CANOPY WATER" ;
        CANWAT:units = "kg m-2" ;
        CANWAT:stagger = "" ;
        CANWAT:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float SSTSK(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        SSTSK:FieldType = 104 ;
        SSTSK:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        SSTSK:description = "SKIN SEA SURFACE TEMPERATURE" ;
        SSTSK:units = "K" ;
        SSTSK:stagger = "" ;
        SSTSK:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float COSZEN(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        COSZEN:FieldType = 104 ;
        COSZEN:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        COSZEN:description = "COS of SOLAR ZENITH ANGLE" ;
        COSZEN:units = "dimensionless" ;
        COSZEN:stagger = "" ;
        COSZEN:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float LAI(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        LAI:FieldType = 104 ;
        LAI:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        LAI:description = "LEAF AREA INDEX" ;
        LAI:units = "m-2/m-2" ;
        LAI:stagger = "" ;
        LAI:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float VAR(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        VAR:FieldType = 104 ;
        VAR:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        VAR:description = "OROGRAPHIC VARIANCE" ;
        VAR:units = "" ;
        VAR:stagger = "" ;
        VAR:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float MAPFAC_M(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        MAPFAC_M:FieldType = 104 ;
        MAPFAC_M:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        MAPFAC_M:description = "Map scale factor on mass grid" ;
        MAPFAC_M:units = "" ;
        MAPFAC_M:stagger = "" ;
        MAPFAC_M:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float MAPFAC_U(Time, south_north, west_east_stag) ;
        MAPFAC_U:FieldType = 104 ;
        MAPFAC_U:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        MAPFAC_U:description = "Map scale factor on u-grid" ;
        MAPFAC_U:units = "" ;
        MAPFAC_U:stagger = "X" ;
        MAPFAC_U:coordinates = "XLONG_U XLAT_U XTIME" ;
    float MAPFAC_V(Time, south_north_stag, west_east) ;
        MAPFAC_V:FieldType = 104 ;
        MAPFAC_V:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        MAPFAC_V:description = "Map scale factor on v-grid" ;
        MAPFAC_V:units = "" ;
        MAPFAC_V:stagger = "Y" ;
        MAPFAC_V:coordinates = "XLONG_V XLAT_V XTIME" ;
    float MAPFAC_MX(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        MAPFAC_MX:FieldType = 104 ;
        MAPFAC_MX:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        MAPFAC_MX:description = "Map scale factor on mass grid, x direction" ;
        MAPFAC_MX:units = "" ;
        MAPFAC_MX:stagger = "" ;
        MAPFAC_MX:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float MAPFAC_MY(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        MAPFAC_MY:FieldType = 104 ;
        MAPFAC_MY:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        MAPFAC_MY:description = "Map scale factor on mass grid, y direction" ;
        MAPFAC_MY:units = "" ;
        MAPFAC_MY:stagger = "" ;
        MAPFAC_MY:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float MAPFAC_UX(Time, south_north, west_east_stag) ;
        MAPFAC_UX:FieldType = 104 ;
        MAPFAC_UX:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        MAPFAC_UX:description = "Map scale factor on u-grid, x direction" ;
        MAPFAC_UX:units = "" ;
        MAPFAC_UX:stagger = "X" ;
        MAPFAC_UX:coordinates = "XLONG_U XLAT_U XTIME" ;
    float MAPFAC_UY(Time, south_north, west_east_stag) ;
        MAPFAC_UY:FieldType = 104 ;
        MAPFAC_UY:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        MAPFAC_UY:description = "Map scale factor on u-grid, y direction" ;
        MAPFAC_UY:units = "" ;
        MAPFAC_UY:stagger = "X" ;
        MAPFAC_UY:coordinates = "XLONG_U XLAT_U XTIME" ;
    float MAPFAC_VX(Time, south_north_stag, west_east) ;
        MAPFAC_VX:FieldType = 104 ;
        MAPFAC_VX:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        MAPFAC_VX:description = "Map scale factor on v-grid, x direction" ;
        MAPFAC_VX:units = "" ;
        MAPFAC_VX:stagger = "Y" ;
        MAPFAC_VX:coordinates = "XLONG_V XLAT_V XTIME" ;
    float MF_VX_INV(Time, south_north_stag, west_east) ;
        MF_VX_INV:FieldType = 104 ;
        MF_VX_INV:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        MF_VX_INV:description = "Inverse map scale factor on v-grid, x direction" ;
        MF_VX_INV:units = "" ;
        MF_VX_INV:stagger = "Y" ;
        MF_VX_INV:coordinates = "XLONG_V XLAT_V XTIME" ;
    float MAPFAC_VY(Time, south_north_stag, west_east) ;
        MAPFAC_VY:FieldType = 104 ;
        MAPFAC_VY:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        MAPFAC_VY:description = "Map scale factor on v-grid, y direction" ;
        MAPFAC_VY:units = "" ;
        MAPFAC_VY:stagger = "Y" ;
        MAPFAC_VY:coordinates = "XLONG_V XLAT_V XTIME" ;
    float F(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        F:FieldType = 104 ;
        F:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        F:description = "Coriolis sine latitude term" ;
        F:units = "s-1" ;
        F:stagger = "" ;
        F:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float E(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        E:FieldType = 104 ;
        E:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        E:description = "Coriolis cosine latitude term" ;
        E:units = "s-1" ;
        E:stagger = "" ;
        E:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float SINALPHA(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        SINALPHA:FieldType = 104 ;
        SINALPHA:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        SINALPHA:description = "Local sine of map rotation" ;
        SINALPHA:units = "" ;
        SINALPHA:stagger = "" ;
        SINALPHA:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float COSALPHA(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        COSALPHA:FieldType = 104 ;
        COSALPHA:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        COSALPHA:description = "Local cosine of map rotation" ;
        COSALPHA:units = "" ;
        COSALPHA:stagger = "" ;
        COSALPHA:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float HGT(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        HGT:FieldType = 104 ;
        HGT:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        HGT:description = "Terrain Height" ;
        HGT:units = "m" ;
        HGT:stagger = "" ;
        HGT:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float TSK(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        TSK:FieldType = 104 ;
        TSK:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        TSK:description = "SURFACE SKIN TEMPERATURE" ;
        TSK:units = "K" ;
        TSK:stagger = "" ;
        TSK:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float P_TOP(Time) ;
        P_TOP:FieldType = 104 ;
        P_TOP:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        P_TOP:description = "PRESSURE TOP OF THE MODEL" ;
        P_TOP:units = "Pa" ;
        P_TOP:stagger = "" ;
    float T00(Time) ;
        T00:FieldType = 104 ;
        T00:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        T00:description = "BASE STATE TEMPERATURE" ;
        T00:units = "K" ;
        T00:stagger = "" ;
    float P00(Time) ;
        P00:FieldType = 104 ;
        P00:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        P00:description = "BASE STATE PRESURE" ;
        P00:units = "Pa" ;
        P00:stagger = "" ;
    float TLP(Time) ;
        TLP:FieldType = 104 ;
        TLP:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        TLP:description = "BASE STATE LAPSE RATE" ;
        TLP:units = "" ;
        TLP:stagger = "" ;
    float TISO(Time) ;
        TISO:FieldType = 104 ;
        TISO:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        TISO:description = "TEMP AT WHICH THE BASE T TURNS CONST" ;
        TISO:units = "K" ;
        TISO:stagger = "" ;
    float TLP_STRAT(Time) ;
        TLP_STRAT:FieldType = 104 ;
        TLP_STRAT:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        TLP_STRAT:description = "BASE STATE LAPSE RATE (DT/D(LN(P)) IN STRATOSPHERE" ;
        TLP_STRAT:units = "K" ;
        TLP_STRAT:stagger = "" ;
    float P_STRAT(Time) ;
        P_STRAT:FieldType = 104 ;
        P_STRAT:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        P_STRAT:description = "BASE STATE PRESSURE AT BOTTOM OF STRATOSPHERE" ;
        P_STRAT:units = "Pa" ;
        P_STRAT:stagger = "" ;
    float MAX_MSTFX(Time) ;
        MAX_MSTFX:FieldType = 104 ;
        MAX_MSTFX:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        MAX_MSTFX:description = "Max map factor in domain" ;
        MAX_MSTFX:units = "" ;
        MAX_MSTFX:stagger = "" ;
    float MAX_MSTFY(Time) ;
        MAX_MSTFY:FieldType = 104 ;
        MAX_MSTFY:MemoryOrder = "0  " ;
        MAX_MSTFY:description = "Max map factor in domain" ;
        MAX_MSTFY:units = "" ;
        MAX_MSTFY:stagger = "" ;
    float RAINC(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        RAINC:FieldType = 104 ;
        RAINC:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        RAINC:description = "ACCUMULATED TOTAL CUMULUS PRECIPITATION" ;
        RAINC:units = "mm" ;
        RAINC:stagger = "" ;
        RAINC:coordinates = "XLONG XLAT XTIME" ;
    float RAINSH(Time, south_north, west_east) ;
        RAINSH:FieldType = 104 ;
        RAINSH:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
        RAINSH:description = "ACCUMULATED SHALLOW CUMULUS
```

Comment: It will be useful if you could add more details. Are you getting errors? Please also format your question better and post the full code. You must be importing something. I have never used the pywrf module, but as far as I recall isn't the wrfout file 3-dimensional for 10m wind speed? So you need something like wd = getvar(ncfile, "wdir")[:,:,:]?

Comment: Please also post the header of the netCDF file `ncdump -h wrfout_d03_2017-06-17_15:00:00`.

Comment: The `bar` functions of an instance of `WindroseAxes` seems to expect the wind direction `wd`, first, and, then, the wind speed `ws` according to [this example from the windrose documentation](https://windrose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). It is the other way around in your code.

Comment: wrfout files won't have wind direction as a single value as far as I know.  They will have u,v components with which you can calculate wind direction.  NCL has a function for that... https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Functions/WRF_arw/wrf_user_getvar.shtml  Though GeoCAT looks to be the future for that group https://wrf-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/internal_api/index.html#routines

Comment: Thanks for the answers everybody.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everybody. I post the header of the netCDF file. I’m beginning with python so I don’t understand much about all this. I tried with my script but I have this error: “too many values to unpack (expected 2). Thanks if someone can help me.